# How can I configure web api's http configuration in bit framework based apps?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, bit-framework

I've configured web api using following code:

```
dependencyManager.RegisterWebApiMiddleware(webApiDependencyManager =>
{
    webApiDependencyManager.RegisterWebApiMiddlewareUsingDefaultConfiguration();
});
```

How can I customize http configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in https://docs.bit-framework.com/docs/bit-server-side/web-api.html#getting-started

You can write:

```
dependencyManager.RegisterWebApiMiddleware(webApiDependencyManager =>
{
    webApiDependencyManager.RegisterWebApiMiddlewareUsingDefaultConfiguration();

    webApiDependencyManager.RegisterGlobalWebApiCustomizerUsing(httpConfiguration =>
    {
        // You've access to web api's http configuration here
    });
});
```